# Symfony 3.3 swiftmailer not send mail on localhost

Tags: php, symfony, email, gmail, swiftmailer

I'm sure everything has been done properly, but the mail is not delivered. Could there be anything else I should try to do?

**config.yml**

```
swiftmailer:
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
encryption: ssl
port:      465
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
spool: { type: memory }
```

**parameter.yml**

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: on*****@gmail.com
mailer_password: ******
```

**controller.php**

```
    echo "mail gönder";
    $this_is = 'this is';
    $the_message = ' the message of the email';
    $mailer = $this->get('mailer');

    // $mailerUser = $this->>container->getParameter('mailer_user))
    // echo $mailerUser;
    //      result on*****@gmail.com

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('The Subject for this Message')
        ->setFrom($this->container->getParameter('mailer_user'))
        ->setTo('onu****@hotmail.com')
        ->setBody($this->renderView('mail/email.html.twig', ['this'=>$this_is, 'message'=>$the_message]))
    ;
    $mailer->send($message);
```

I have tried too much of an attempt but failed. I am using Nginx server. Could this be the reason?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with the transport `gmail` like explained in [Symfony's doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/gmail.html).

Answer (score 0):

Oww.

I solved the problem, but the solution seemed a bit strange to me. I ended mail class with the `die;` command. The problem is solved when use `return $this->redirectToRoute(...).`

I think it reason in the spool parameter. [Spool Email.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html)

Comment: `When you use spooling to store the emails to memory, they will get sent right before the kernel terminates.` When you do `die;` it will not execute the kernel code so will not send mails. But with `return ...` Symfony will continue to do some stuff, like sending your mails ;)

Comment: Your explanations were more efficient than the explanations in the documentation :) thanks

Comment: The comment by mykiwi saved my bacon.